# Rails 5 - How to get total entries using will_paginate and Active Model Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

I'm using `will_paginate` and `api-pagination` to paginate my data and `active_model_serializers` for JSON serialization.
I want to send the total entries of the resource to the client where I'm using AngularJS.

**Controller code**

```
def index
    comp_id = params[:company_id]
    cat_id = params[:category_id]
    if comp_id
      if comp_id && cat_id
        product = Product.where(:company_id => comp_id, :category_id => cat_id)
      else
        product = Product.where(:company_id => comp_id)
      end
      paginate json: product,meta: pagination_dict(product), status: 200
    else
      render json: { errors: "Company ID is NULL" }, status: 422
    end
  end
```

**Serializer**

```
 class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :mrp, :sp, :cp, :stocks, :isPublished
  has_one :category
end
```

How can I include the total_count in my response?

**Update**

I tried adding the following method in my base controller as per [this](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/howto/add_pagination_links.md) doc, however I'm getting undefined method error for all the methods defined.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Authenticable
  include Rails::Pagination
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  def render_404
    render json: { errors: 'The requested resource cannot be found' }, status: 404
  end

  def pagination_dict(collection)
    {
      #current_page: collection.current_page,
      #next_page: collection.next_page,
      #prev_page: collection.prev_page, # use collection.previous_page when using will_paginate
      total_pages: collection.total_pages,
      total_count: collection.total_count
    }

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods (`total_pages`, `total_entries`...) work only on `paginated` ActiveRecord relation.

For example, `Product.where(company_id: comp_id).page(1).total_pages` returns the number of total pages, because the relation uses `pagination`.

In your case, why not just use ActiveRecord's `count` method to get the total number of entries?

```
paginate json: product, meta: product.count, status: 200
```